# Sublime Text: delete file in group?

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm looking for a way to *delete* from the system (not just remove from the opened session) a given file, within Sublime 3 (3103).

The file in question is opened in Sublime, and shows in the sidebar in a **Group**.

I've installed the [Sidebar Enhancements](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements) but this only adds the option, in the context menu, to delete a file that is opened within a **Folder**.

For files in **Groups**, right clicking on its name in the sidebar only shows the options: *Close, Close Others, Close Others Below, New File, Open File*.

Is there some way of performing this rather simple task that I might be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Try:

## [**TabsExtra**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/TabsExtra)

---

It gives you the ability to delete files from tab right-click menus.